# Commands to "simulate" removing and re-inserting a USB peripheral?

Tags: webcam

I use motion on a Raspberry Pi, and sometimes the camera feed hangs. The camera is physically mounted, and it is kind of awkward to remove the cable and insert it again, so I was wondering:

Is there a way of achieving the same effect programmatically?

Comment: Hi - Could you accept an answer please :D seems like some answers here have helped many people in your situation.. wondering if it helped you too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question and good idea. Shuckle suggests some code that resets the USB bus for the device, which may clear up some problems. See official forum:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=219980#p219980

I quote his c code, which I have not tested yet:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/usbdevice_fs.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *filename;
    int fd;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Give USB device name as parameter\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    filename = argv[1];
    fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("USB device open failed");
        exit(2);
    }
    if (ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0) == -1) {
        perror("USBDEVFS_RESET device ioctl failed");
        exit(3);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

You then use this code by saying, basically:

```
usbreset /dev/bus/usb/001/004
```

You could get the bus numbers from lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:092f Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Express Plus
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
```

Now you've got me curious about whether that would fix a problem with the old Express Plus, I'll try that soon!

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, I shall surely test it! Do let us know if it fixes your Express Plus-related problem. :-)

Comment: It didn't *fix* my problem, but the code given above does seem to reset the bus and prevent the camera from getting stuck in a broken state. Also, firmware updates continue to improve the USB performance for these questionable cameras. ** Linux psychic 3.6.11+ #414 PREEMPT Thu Apr 18 02:00:59 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
**

Answer (score 7):

You can make USB devices disappear using sysfs. I have tested this with a Logitech Unifying USB receiver. Although `lsusb` listed the device, key presses weren't processed when the device was removed using this method.

1. Determine the ID associated with your USB device using `dmesg`. For instance, after plugging the USB receiver in, I get `1-1.2` as ID:

   ```
   usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
   usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
   usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
   usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Receiver
   usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
   ```
2. Remove and re-insert the device:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo 1-1.2 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind'
   sudo sh -c 'echo 1-1.2 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind'
   ```
3. Profit!

You may also have success by writing unbind and bind on the driver for your camera driver. Use `ls -l /dev/bus/[DRIVER]/devices` to determine the driver.

(Inspired by [an answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13035/8250))

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of sharing, I modified the `usbreset` code provided, in Tai's [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6782/commands-to-simulate-removing-and-re-inserting-a-usb-peripheral#answer-6787) above, to accept parameters like you get from `lsusb` (in addition).  That way it can be invoked conveniently by

```
DEVNUMS=`lsusb | grep -i webcam | tr -d : | awk '{print $2, $4;}'`
/home/xyz/cam/usbreset $DEVNUMS
```

which turns, for example, into

```
/home/xyz/cam/usbreset 001 018
```

The code is at the end.

I found the Pi USB webcam driver crashed often, but this is a way to recover it.  It was easiest to make the executable be su root.

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char devicename[1024];
    const char *filename = devicename;
    int fd;

    if ( 2 > argc || 3 < argc ) {
        printf("Give USB device name as parameter\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( 2 == argc ) 
        filename = argv[1];
    else
        sprintf( devicename, "/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s", argv[1], argv[2] );

    printf( "Resetting USB device '%s'\n", filename );

    fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("USB device open failed");
        exit(2);
    }
    if (ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0) == -1) {
        // Don't care!  It usually does, when we need to reset it.
        //perror("USBDEVFS_RESET device ioctl failed");
        //exit(3);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try un-mounting and mounting the USB drive?

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /path/to/usb
$ sudo umount /path/to/usb
```

The first line is making /path/to/usb the mount point of the usb port at /dev/sda1 (you'll have to check to see which port it is connected to each time you plug it in).

The second line is unmounting the port through the alias

Comment: I think the OP means physically mounted, and it's hard to unplug as a result. :)

Comment: Yes, physically mounted. (And it's not a USB drive, by the way, it's a camera.)